# Is the homotopy category of an abelian model category abelian?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, model-categories

A model structure on an abelian category $A$ is called an *abelian model structure* if the cofibrations are precisely the monomorphisms with cofibrant cokernel, and if the fibrations are precisely the epimorphisms with fibrant kernel. This terminology was introduced by Mark Hovey in [Cotorsion pairs, model category structures, and representation theory](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00209-002-0431-9); see also the survey article [Cotorsion pairs and model categories](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~bshipley/hovey.pdf).

In his book, Hovey introduced *monoidal model categories* and proved that their homotopy categories are also monoidal. Similarly, a model category is *stable* if and only if it's homotopy category is triangulated. I always assumed from the terminology that the condition about (co)fibrations was there to guarantee that the homotopy category of an abelian model category would be an abelian category, but now I can't find a reference for this, and I'm not even sure if it's true. I'm trying to branch out a bit into homological algebra and representation theory, and abelian model categories are new to me. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No. The projective model structure on chain complexes of modules over a ring is an abelian model category, and the homotopy category is the derived category, which is never abelian unless the ring is semisimple.

Comment: Same for the motivating example in Hovey’s paper: the stable module category is triangulated and usually not abelian.

Comment: Ok great, thanks! Sorry for the dumb question!

Comment: Quick follow-up question: is the homotopy category of an abelian model category always triangulated at least? In other words, does abelian imply stable?

Comment: @JeremyRickard, nevermind, I can answer my follow-up question. You only know the homotopy category is triangulated if the abelian model category is *hereditary* (I'm not sure if this is an "iff", and I doubt it). Without this condition you only know it's "pre-triangulated", as I learned from II.2.1.20 of Hanno Becker's PhD thesis.